# Mongodb query result using find or aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

It's been some hours now that I'm looking for an answer for my small query problem on mongoDB.

Here is my data structure:

```
{
    UserDocuments: {
        id: 1,
        count: 5,
        totalSize: 500000,
        documents: [
         {name: "A", type: "pdf", categories: ["cat A", "cat B", "cat C"], size: 100000},
         {name: "B", type: "doc", categories: ["cat A", "cat D", "cat E"], size: 100000},
         {name: "D", type: "pdf", categories: ["cat F", "cat G", "cat H"], size: 100000},
         {name: "C", type: "pdf", categories: ["cat F", "cat G", "cat H"], size: 100000},
         {name: "E", type: "pdf", categories: ["cat A", "cat G", "cat H"], size: 100000},
        ]
    }
}
```

Now I need to retrive all document with for example cat A and to have the result like this:

```
{
    UserDocuments: {
        id: 1,
        count: 3, <- If possible
        totalSize: 300000, <- If possible
        documents: [
         {name: "A", type: "pdf", categories: ["cat A", "cat B", "cat C"], size: 100000},
         {name: "B", type: "doc", categories: ["cat A", "cat D", "cat E"], size: 100000},             
         {name: "E", type: "pdf", categories: ["cat A", "cat G", "cat H"], size: 100000},
        ]
    }
}
```

I've tried to do this using find and $elemMatch in order to first at least have all the documents (the count and  size are not that important for now). But $elemMatch returns only the first element of the documents are, in this case the {name: "A".....}.

Then I've seen that aggregate might help me but with aggregate I was only able to return the documents array and not all the information of my userDocuments, like the id, the size and the totalSize.

How can I do to have this king of results, what can I edit in order for the query to get me those results:

```
// This return 3 time the UserDocuments with all infos but only with one element 
// in the documents array, so I have redundant informations

db.doc.aggregate({
    $match: {id: "1", "documents.categories": "A"}},
    {$unwind: "documents"},
    {$match: {"documents.categories": "A"}}
)
```

I've also tried with $filter but with no succes because the projection does not include the userDocuments fields.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Matching `"documents.categories": "A"` should not return any document. Also, after `$unwind` maybe you need `$group`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like following

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$documents" },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $in: [ "cat A", "$documents.categories" ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$id",
      "count": { "$sum": 1 },
      "totalSize": { $sum: "$documents.size" },
      "documents": { $push: "$documents" }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dQIO2vnZmqX)**